# Cannot access included files SourceGenerator

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I added this ItemGroup to the SourceGenerator.csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="defs\*\*.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
        <Content Include="Templates\*.template" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

OBS: The files get copied to the output if i build the SourceGenerator project.

I get the path of the template file like this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Templates", _fileName);
```

But, while trying to compile the Project that references this SourceCode generator i get an warning:

```
Generator 'SourceGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'DirectoryNotFoundException' with message 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300-preview.22204.3\Roslyn\bincore\Templates\Struct.template'.'
```

Comment: Configure them as analyzer additional files and access them through the source-generators context. Analyzers and SGs work directly on the compilation and normal content files are not part of it, so source-generators should not depend on them.

Comment: Also, i'd strongly recommend using `.editorconfig` for analyzer and SG configuration.